# How can i filter a List from 1 to 101 for numbers that are multiple dividable?

Tags: python, list, function, lambda, filter

Im asked to filter a function. The specific term is:

> Create the variable `filter_t3` that contains the filter function to create a generator for all numbers from 1 to 101 (both inclusive) that are dividable by 7, 13, or 42.
>
> Then, use the `list()` function to create a list with the name `result_t3` which contains the filtered elements (the ones that match the expression above).
>
> Hint: Use a `lambda` function in the expression parameter of filter.

Thanks for the help!!
Stay safe and sound!

Comment: Please add what you searched (read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about How to ask a good question): *"keep track of what you find"*.

Comment: I mean, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First, you assign a function that returns a bool when the number is divisible by the ones you have and store it in the lambda, I'm sure there are better ways to do this but this one works fine.
Then, we create the list from 1 to 101 which I named `num_list`.
Finally, we apply the `filter` function to the list and store the result in a new list called `result_t3`.

```
filter_t3 = lambda x: (x % 7 == 0 or x % 13 == 0 or x % 42 == 0)
num_list =  list(range(1, 102))
result_t3 = filter(filter_t3, num_list)

print(num_list)
print(result_t3)
```

I'd encourage you to read about the [filter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter) function and how to use [lambdas](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) with [them](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-filter-python-examples/).

EDIT: Since `range` is only inclusive to the first number, I changed 101 to 102 after the comma.

EDIT2: I need to learn how to read, you said dividable by x OR y, changed the lambda to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you are looking for:

```
filter_t3 = filter(lambda x: x % 7 == 0 or x % 13 == 0 or x % 42 == 0,range(1, 102))

result_t3 = list(filter_t3)
```